# how to monitor a unix directory and if any new file in directory it will be copied to another directory

Tags: solaris, cp, inotify

I want to monitor a unix(Solaris 10) directory and if there is any new file I want to copy it immediately.

Tried:
I have shown inotifywait and incron package in Linux for it but I don't know whether it is compatible for unix or not. How I can perform this task in Solaris 10.

Be noted that I have root privilege.

Comment: There's`lsyncd` which combines inotify (or, possibly, other mechanisms) with rsync, but I have no experience with it on Solaris.

Comment: Once you identify any new file, how do you know the file is not just partially complete?  How are you going to tell it's fully written?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rsync` linux utility. You need to specify source and destination,it works locally as well as remotely. Please check `man rsync` for more details. For solaris, you'll need to install it.

Comment: Does rsync monitor a directory?  I've always run it as a cron job.

Comment: @ChadClark: Yes it monitors directory/file for changes.

Comment: *`rsync` linux utility.*?  On a Solaris system?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Please read full answer, I have mentioned to install it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Solaris [File Events Notification](http://blogs.oracle.com/praks/entry/file_events_notification). One approach shown [here](http://solarisrants.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/solaris-file-event-notification/). Requires at least Solaris v11 though.

Answer (score 0):

We had good experience with [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch). From the README:

> A cross-platform file change monitor with multiple backends: Apple OS X File System Events, *BSD kqueue, **Solaris/Illumos** File Events Notification,

Answer (score -3):

You may use while loop...

```
for (( ; ; ))
do
cp -f /source/*.txt /destination >> /dev/null
sleep 2
done
```

Used /dev/null to avoid displaying errors.

Comment: waste of system resources